# How do I add all the numbers in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with some Ip's and some numbers. I want to add all the numbers in the array for every IP

So if I return my array to the browser it looks like this:

```
Array ( 
     [72.00.00.000] => 9962 9980 9984 215 9997 
     [90.00.00.000] => 6157 1586 8422 336
```

Now I want to add the numbers in the array for just every IP

Then it should look like this:

```
[72.00.00.000] => 40138
[90.00.00.000] => 16501
```

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
foreach ($topTenIp as $val) {
        $bytes_ips[$val] = shell_exec("grep $val /var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/domain.log | awk '{print $10}'");
    }

    foreach ( $bytes_ips as $ip => $numList ) {
        $tot = array_sum(explode(' ', $numList));
        echo sprintf("%s => %d\n", $ip, $tot);
    }
```

The result I get is:

```
72.00.00.000 => 9962 
90.00.00.000 => 6157
```

Solved Code:

```
foreach ($topTenIp as $val) {
    $bytes_ips[$val] = shell_exec("grep $val /var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/domain.log | awk '{print $10}'");
}
foreach ( $bytes_ips as $ip => $numList ) {
    $tot = array_sum(explode("\n", $numList));
    echo sprintf("[%s] => %d\n", $ip, $tot);
}
```

Comment: Is the array you have shown us the result of the `shell_exec(bla bla)` i.e. is it the contents of the `$bytes_ips` array?

Comment: yes it is the result of the shell_exec command :)

Comment: So now.... Do you want to add `(9962+9980+9984+215+9997) + (6157+1586+8422+336)`

Comment: yes this is right :) i just dont know how to code this... 

i want it like : IP => 100000 OtherIP => 2000000) ......

Comment: for exampe : IP xyz => 5 10  IP abc => 50 20 

and i want to add the numbers for every IP itself - so the result should look like this :  IP xyz => 15 IP abc => 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you will have to treat each occurrence of `$byte_ips` seperately and break all the space seperated numbers into an array and then add up the array. Like this

```
$byte_ips = array(
    '72.00.00.000' => '9962 9980 9984 215 9997',
    '90.00.00.000' => '6157 1586 8422 336'
);

// debugging only
print_f($byte_ips):
// end debugging
foreach ( $byte_ips as $ip => $numList ) {
    $tot = array_sum(explode(' ', $numList));
    echo sprintf("[%s] => %d\n", $ip, $tot);
}
```

Result is:

```
[72.00.00.000] => 40138
[90.00.00.000] => 16501
```

And now you have found that the numbers in `$byte_ips` array are actually seperated by Newlines and not spaces as your original question stated, the code should be :-

```
foreach ( $byte_ips as $ip => $numList ) {
    $tot = array_sum(explode("\n", $numList));
    echo sprintf("[%s] => %d\n", $ip, $tot);
}
```

If you want the result in Megabytes then you have to cast the number which is actually a string representaion of a number to an integer, so that you can actually do arithmetic on it, and then change the formatting in the `sprintf` to output the result as a floating point number

```
foreach ( $byte_ips as $ip => $numList ) {
    $tot = array_sum(explode("\n", $numList));
    $tot = ((int)$tot / 1024 / 1024);
    echo sprintf("[%s] => %.6f\n", $ip,$tot);
}
```

Now you get

```
[72.00.00.000] => 0.038279
[90.00.00.000] => 0.015737
```

Comment: this isnt want i want exactly... 

youre just addet every number together.. but i just want to add the numbers for the first IP together, then all the numbers of the seccond IP together.. and so on

Comment: Yea, I didnt see your additional explanation until I posted the initial solution, I have amended it now I know all your requirements

Comment: the result in your answer is exactly what i want.. i dont know why but your code return me the first number of every IP - i really cant see why but it havent addet anything :o

Comment: could you tell me how do i mark my text in the commentbox? then i can show you the result :)

Comment: i addet something to your answer :)

Comment: Php 7.0.0 is what i'm using now :)

Comment: It still runs ok in PHP7 for me

Comment: wait a minute, i will show you how my code know exactly looks like

Comment: oh sorry.. now i saved it -- sorry xD

Comment: Oh is that all. Then just remove the `IP ` from the `sprintf()` See my latest edit

Comment: i dont understand why my result isnt like yours.. i did exactly the same like you but i still just get the first number of the IP.. the code doesnt add the numbers :/

Comment: no that wasnt that what i want.. i will edit my quesion.. wait a sec please

Comment: Okay I changed my answer, you probably should have a quick look at the `sprinf()` [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: and of course i'm really gratefull for your help ! i just had a meeting at my work so thats why I'm gone.. and if my problem is solved i will tidy up my quesion for others with the same problem ! but its still the same problem.. and another thanks for the sprintf manual - this will definetly help my soon

Comment: I changed the `sprintf()` to format as you requested, have you spotted that new code?

Comment: yes i saw it.. but it still just gives me the first byte of every IP and i cant see why... i saw the manuals of sprintf and i unterstood them.. i really dont know why it wont work.. This is what they give me ----- [72.000.00.00] => 9962 [90.000.00.00] => 6157

Comment: Ok, add the little bit of debugging code so we can see **exactly** what the `$byte_ips` array looks like. Add the output from that to your question

Comment: what do you mean with "little bit of debugging code" - you want to see the output of $byte_ips?

Comment: wait ! i solved it ! the problem is just ridiculous haha :) its because of this line :  $tot = array_sum(explode(' ', $numList)); --- i need to change the ' ' in the explode to "\n" - now it works perfectly :) - i will add this to my question :)

Comment: oh.. havent seen it... but okay - thanks a lot :) this will help me a lot in my project :3 i addet the answer to my question and renamed the name to SOLVED - is there any other thing i need to do? i'm kinda new here :)

Comment: i did :) do you maybe know how i can turn the output into megabytes? the numbers now are the bytes.. i tried it with ------------ : $sum = ($split / 1024 / 1024); --- but this havent work

Comment: if I use " / " it gives me a : Unsupported operand types

Comment: Yes give me a couple of ticks

Comment: LOL: There you go, 2 answers for the price of one.

Comment: hehe why not :D so.. do you know how do i get the numbers in mb?